# Can I use my localhost server for a public website?

Tags: php

Can I use my PhpMyAdmin(localhost) for a public website? Or can it only be used from this specific computer?

What I want to do is to code a login form in HTML and PHP, then connect it to my localhost and put the website online. Or would my website refer to their localhost and then return an error because they couldn't find that database in their server?

Comment: local host refers to the machine ( server ) it is running on.  If you want to host your own site, you would need a static IP at the least.

Comment: This link might be useful ([https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostnameathome.html](https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostnameathome.html))

Comment: Try ngrok software which tunnels your localhost any port to live website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The long answer is yes, but with some caveats.

1. Your ISP may not allow port 80 (or 443 which is SSL) through to your local server.
2. You will need to open a port in your firewall and direct it to your local IP address
3. Your public IP address (assuming you have a residential account) may change without warning, so you'll have to use DynDNS or something to keep track.
4. Generally not a good idea given that actual hosting is so cheap.
5. If you just want it for personal learning, etc. go for it. I highly recommend against using it for business purposes.